# How to feed sound as input to neural networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, signal-processing

I am planning to build a software which can classify a piece of music as good or bad using artificial neural networks. For this, I need to convert audio into some numerical values to feed to NN as input. So for training the NN, I first downloaded billboard hot 100 songs (which I believe should classify as good music), and also downloaded some bad noise audio files (which will classify as bad music). Then I converted them to .wav format and then split each file into multiple .wav files of length 2 seconds each. I was planning to use fast fourier transform to convert these audio clippings to frequency - amplitude pairs, but the problem is, even if we use a 2 second clip, its FFT would generate array of about 100,000 such pairs. And doing this to thousands of audio files would generate too big dataset with too many features.
I wanted to know is there any way we could shorten this dataset, while keeping the 'essence of music' in it so that better predictions can be made? Or should I use some other algorithm/ process?

Comment: " planning to build a software"  OK, do that then come back with code that we might help you fix. i.e. "Here is my code to do x, how can I make it more efficient/smaller or better define y" etc.

Comment: This isn't really the place for that. - also, you'd be training your CNN on 2-second snippets of "good" music, not the whole song. This means you'll have a machine that is very good at identifying 2-second long segments of "good" music, but not a machine that is good at identifying a "good" _track_

Comment: Please note that "good" in this case is not "good" but "similar to current billboard hot 100" (which changes over time)  "Good" to me differs greatly from my friend Charlie.

Comment: most audio processing libraries in python aren't robust enough to generate FFT of that much long clip. if 2 sec long clip can generate 100,000 fft pairs then imagine how big of data would a 3 min song give?

Comment: I used 'hot 100 list of all times'. Not some current month 'gucci gang' type song list...

Comment: Think about "process THIS song, compare to x set where x set is the sample (hot 100), then keep a flag for each (good/bad/similar whatever)" and store that - now go find or build something to do that.  Given a limited x set, you can store that, even if huge as it is static, even though that static is a mountain now you can optimize your mountain climb.

Comment: That's only the problem my friend, The training data will be having too many features ~100,000. and thus will be grossly over-fitted. So is there any way to shorten the dataset?

Comment: This is super broad at this point as stated - it is like asking "How can I build X" where X might be Twitter me a song, Google for good Songs, Dreads Song Mapper, Derddeds People playing good songs near me etc. which is where YOUR value is (you figured out how to do that) and thus YOUR effort has value i.e. you become the expert in this/your desired algorithm such as how to quickly/efficiently determine the "goodness", rank that etc.  **Keep in mind that the value add here DOES appear to be what/how you solve this problem, we see that however the effort for US to do so will not be trivial**

Comment: Compute the power spectrum from the FFT for each 2 second clip, partition it into frequency bins corresponding to the musical notes, and just use the total power in each bin.   It won't be awesome, but just about anything you do will be sufficient to distinguish music from noise.

Answer (score 6):

At first, you can [extract the various audio features](https://github.com/lazymahendrathapa/Sarangi-II/tree/master/App/src/main/java/com/sarangi/audioFeatures) like:

1) Compactness.
2) Magnitude spectrum.
3) Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients.
4) Pitch.
5) Power Spectrum.
6) RMS.
7) Rhythm.
8) Spectral Centroid.
9) Spectral Flux.
10) Spectral RollOff Point.
11) Spectral Variability.
12) Zero Crossings.

After generating the feature set you have two options:

A) Aggregate the particular feature of a song by taking mean [and/or variance], concatenate the whole features for a song, then feed into the Artifical Neural Network and perform the classification task.

B) Use the [Recurrent Neural Network](https://github.com/ruohoruotsi/LSTM-Music-Genre-Classification) for the classification task.